# Having a Textfile in favorites

Tags: 18.04

I have a text file that I would like to have quick access to.  I would like it to show in the shortcuts "bar" with my other shortcuts.

In order to do this, I know that I am supposed to create a file
~/.local/share/applications/custom-filemanager.desktop

and put "code" that looks something like this into the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=notes

Exec=gedit-open home/user1/Desktop/notes

Comment=Launch notes

Terminal=false

Icon=accessories-text-editor
```

However, part of what I wrote there must be wrong because although it creates the "shortcut," nothing happens when I click on the shortcut.  I am unsure of what I should put for Type, Exec, and Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is invalid. gedit-open doesn't exist. The correct command is gedit. Also a slash is missing from the file path.
So, change:

Exec=gedit-open home/user1/Desktop/notes

to:

**Exec=gedit /home/user1/Desktop/notes**

Comment: At first I changed it to Exec=gedit home/user1/Desktop/notes (I didn't have the / before the path).  If that created an unwanted directory somewhere, I'd like to delete it.  I thought it might have created something in ~/.local/share/applications/ but I don't see any new directory there.